# How do you tilt a skybox in Unity while using MRTK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, skybox

I'm develping using Unity and MRTK. I'm using the VideoPlayer and the Skybox/Panoramic texture to render a stereoscopic video on the skybox, which works fine until I'm seated in a different position, in an armchair for example, with my head not completely perpendicular to the horizon.

I know there is a way to orbit the skybox, but what I need is to rotate it along the x axis (movement from top to botom). Any way to do this? Otherwise, how could I rotate that movie/clip I'm playing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is most likely not kosher, but I solved my problem by rotating the MixedRealtyPlayspace transform. Really not ideal, but it works....